# How can I tell if a Batch variable is text or a number?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

This is a really simple thing that I'm having a horrible time figuring out.

I have a script. It breaks the date down into separate vars, like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ( 'DATE /T' ) do set DD=%%a&set MM=%%b&set YYYY=%%c
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=:." %%e in ("%time%") do set HH=%%e&set MI=%%f&set SS=%%g
```

This is great in cmd! Until I make the script a scheduled task. When it's a scheduled task, the first token in `DATE /T` is the Day Name (as in Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.) The problem is that I need it to be the Date, and not the day.

To me, this should be a simple if statement to check if `%%A` is a number, but I cannot figure out how to check this. I've trawled through old blogs and questions here, but I've come up empty. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to set a variable as a number:

```
set /a x=TUE
id "%x%"="0" echo this is not a number
```

But I recommend using a language independent solution:

```
for /f %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime^|find "."') do set x=%%i
set YYYY=%x:~0,4%
set MM=%x:~4,2%
set DD=%x:~6,2%
set HH=%x:~8,2%
set MI=%x:~10,2%
set SS=%x:~12,2%
```

or, if you don't mind using other variable names and a missing leading `0` (like `8` for August instead of `08`) :

```
for /f %%i in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /value ^|find "="') do set %%i
```

and get

```
Day=22
Hour=17
Minute=19
Month=8
Second=12
Year=2014
```

Answer (score 1):

The date variable is unreliable when the code could run on different machines.

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%" & set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original scenario which made you to think whether a string is a text or number - 
it is always best to use the wmic code to determine the date and time in windows as it returns the values in ISO standard and it is same irrespective of regional settings. Below is the code.

```
for /f %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^| findstr /b [0-9]') do set TS=%%x

set yyyy=%TS:~0,4%
set mm=%TS:~4,2%
set dd=%TS:~6,2%
set hh=%TS:~8,2%
set min=%TS:~10,2%
set timestamp=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%_%hh%-%min%
echo %timestamp%
```

In response to your question here - Below may help you to understand how to find a variable is a text or number.

```
@echo off   
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f %%i in (input.txt) do (  
    (echo.%%i | findstr /i [a-z] >nul) || (echo.%%i | findstr /i [0-9] >nul) && echo.%%i is a number
    (echo.%%i | findstr /i [0-9] >nul) || (echo.%%i | findstr /i [a-z] >nul) && echo.%%i is a text
    (echo.%%i | findstr /i [0-9] >nul) && (echo.%%i | findstr /i [a-z] >nul) && echo.%%i is a text and number
)
```

Example(tested) output -

```
D:\Scripts>type input.txt
1234
abcd
123abc
Hello world
12345
welcome
we1c0me

D:\Scripts>draft.bat
1234 is a number
abcd is a text
123abc is a text and number
Hello is a text
12345 is a number
welcome is a text
we1c0me is a text and number
```

Cheers, G

Answer (score 0):

First, I suspect you're running into regional settings differences.  Your scheduled task is probably running in a different account, with different settings.  (I get the day-name first on my system when running from CMD.)  Even if you stripped off the day of the week, you might have problems with the order of the numbers (e.g., mine is MM-DD-YYYY).

That said... if you just want to skip the day-of-week text, the absolute easiest change to your script would be as follows:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ " %%a in ('DATE /T') do set DD=%%a&set MM=%%b&set YYYY=%%c
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=:." %%e in ("%time%") do set HH=%%e&set MI=%%f&set SS=%%g
```

This just treats all (English) alpha characters as delimiters, so the FOR command happily skips them.

To answer your question more directly: if you want to check to see if a value is a number, you can try something like this:

```
set VAL_TO_TEST=...
set /a VAL=%VAL_TO_TEST%+0
if "%VAL%"=="%VAL_TO_TEST%" echo VAL_TO_TEST is a number
```

This relies on SET's rather loose expression parsing (it generally treats anything it can't parse as a zero).  You may run into problems with this technique if the input string is oddly formatted (extra whitespace, etc), but that won't be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

```
set "yyyy=" & for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%a in (
    'robocopy "|" . /njh /nocopy /l'
) do if not defined yyyy (
    set "yyyy=%%a" & set "mm=%%b" & set "dd=%%c" 
    set "hh=%%d" & set "nn=%%e" & set "ss=%%f"
)

echo %yyyy% %mm% %dd% %hh% %nn% %ss%
```

This uses `robocopy` to generate a error and retrieve the date/time from the output

Comment: Good to know this, but this may fail on the older systems (esp windows 2003 server) does not have robocopy inbuilt.

Comment: @gbabu, you are right. I included this here because the windows 2012 tag. Anyway, `robocopy` for windows 2003 or XP is available from Microsoft inside the freely downloadable *Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools*